# Autofac - use in bigger project (one global container?)

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac, ioc-container

I am trying to figure out how to use Autofac in a bigger solution than the simple examples that you find everywhere.

**My question is how do you structure everything? The only option I found is to use one global container:**

Sample project layout:

MyProject solution:

- DataAccess

  - Data
- Business

  - Managers
  - Engines
- Hosts

  - TestHost
- Core

  - Bootstrapper

Let's say I am hosting WCF service.

in my host class, in main method I am instantiating the container:

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyProject.Bootsrapper.ServiceProvider.Container container = MyProject.Bootsrapper.ServiceProvider.RegisterAllINeed();

        ...
        TestManager mngr = new TestManager();
        var query = mngr.Test();
        ...
    }
```

MyProject.Bootsrapper.ServiceProvider.RegisterAllINeed() is a static method in a static class that returns:

```
ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
(...)
builder.build();
```

and MyProject.Bootstrapper.ServiceProvider.Container is a static property that holds the reference to my global container.

It means that I need to have a project that has references to EVERYTHING that will be injected. So MyProject.Bootstrapper.ServiceProvider would have references to MyProject.DataAccess, MyProject.Business.Managers, MyProject.Business.Engines etc.

It feels like it is a bad practice or is it the way to go?

**Side question: I understand that with that solution I should register all the assemblies to have autofac now to which inject the dependencies?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It means that I need to have a project that has references to EVERYTHING that will be injected.

The application's startup project will *always* reference all other projects, either directly, or indirectly, since dependencies are transitive. This concept of wiring the whole application in the start-up path is called the Composition Root.

[This article](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/) gives a detailed description of what a Composition Root is, and *why* it is okay for it to reference all other projects.